# GREP to select footnote text and make it inline note

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, grep, footnotes, affinity-publisher

Now I am finished with my magazine for sighted people and want to get it ready to Braille for the blind. In the process, I need to change the footnotes to inline notes.

Is there a way to use GREP to select the footnote text and insert it as an inline note directly after the footnote reference? (See images below.)

There is a macro to do it in MS Word, but if there would be a way to do it in Indesign or Affinity Publisher with Grep  find and replace, it would be preferable because I could do a multiple find and replace and do all my changes at once. (For Braille, I need to change tabs to double space, etc.)

Word macro here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/convert-footnote-to-inline-citation/6e2cc6cc-add0-4af9-abc0-1c6e14e9c7ac

Thanks for your help!

[image: Original copy showing standard Indesign footnotes]

[image: File ready for Braille with the footnotes converted to inline notes-highlighted for contrast]